# I am making a website using django and tailwind css. But in Cpanel I am getting this command error of Node Js path. Any suggestions what I can do?

Tags: node.js, django, tailwind-css

CommandError:
It looks like node.js and/or npm is not installed or cannot be found.

Visit https://nodejs.org to download and install node.js for your system.

If you have npm installed and still getting this error message, set NPM_BIN_PATH variable in settings.py to match path of NPM executable in your system.

Example:
NPM_BIN_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/npm"

Answer (score 14):

For windows user, add

```
NPM_BIN_PATH = "C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd"
```

to `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out if Node is installed on your hosting environment, you can use:

node -v

If this returns a version, then it is an indicator that there is NodeJS installed by default. And to find out the full path to the node binary, use:

whereis node

OR

which node

Once you got the full path, define it inside the settings.py of your Django.

However, if you still experience difficulties with that, I would strongly recommend finding a managed NodeJS web hosting provider that will natively have NodeJS and their support can help with such questions.